# Symfony form output

Tags: forms, symfony

I render a form in my application:

`{{ form_widget(form.weeks) }}`

The options come from a entity query builder.
I want to check in view  `if($entitiy->getBooked()){ echo disabled }` on each option. (so they can not select booked options).
But how can I do that?

if I do that manual the `{{ form_rest(form) }}` will put a new select on the bottom.

formBuilder:

```
$builder->add( 'weeks', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Mitch\NameBundle\Entity\CaravanRow',
    'property' => 'line',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er ) use ( $caravan ) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('w')
                  ->orderBy('w.dateFrom', 'ASC')
                  ->where('w.caravan = :caravan' )
                  ->andWhere('w.visible = 1')
                  ->setParameter( 'caravan', $caravan );
    },
    'attr' => array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'size'     => 5,
        'style'    => 'width: 415px;'
    ),
));
```

Comment: And you don't want to limit the query with an `"AND w.booked = 0"`?

Comment: No I want to show them all the weeks they can book, but if they already booked I want to make that option disabled

Comment: I've done this sort of thing in my own forms but I don't have a generic answer to do this right now but one option would be to create your `Form Type` and a matching [twig field block](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field). Withing the twig template you'd be able to easily set the disabled attribute as needed.